# String Scramble - replacing characters not working correctly

Tags: c, string, replace

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("------------------------\n");
  printf("WELCOME TO THE SCRAMBLER\n");
  printf("------------------------\n\n");

  char userString[21];
  printf("Please input a String :> ");
  scanf("%s", userString);
  printf("\n\nTo cancel, please press the # key\n\n");

  char mytarget[2];
  char myreplace[2];

  while(1)
  {
          bool notfoundFlag = false;
          printf("Target : ");
          scanf("%s", &mytarget[0]);

          if(mytarget[0] == '#')
          {
                    break;
          }        

          printf("Replace with : ");
          scanf("%s", &myreplace[0]);

          int j;              
          for(j = 0; userString[j] !='\0'; j++)
          {
                if(userString[j] != mytarget[0])
                {
                                 printf("Character not found, try again\n\n");
                                 notfoundFlag = true;
                                 break;
                }
                break;
          }
          if(notfoundFlag)continue;
          printf("Replacing %s with %s\n", &mytarget[0], &myreplace[0]);  

          char newStr[21];             
          newStr[21] = userString[21];
          int i;
          for(i = 0; newStr[i] != '\0'; i++)
          {
                if(newStr[i] == mytarget[0])
                {
                                 newStr[i] = myreplace[0];
                }
          }

          printf("\nWord is : \" %s \" \n\n", &newStr);
}

printf("\n\n");
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
```

The problem I am having is that after I have entered mytarget and myreplace, when the string scrambles I returns gibberish characters, and I have no idea what im doing wrong, can anybody help me out? Im fairly new to programming and very new to the C language (started with Java)

Comment: Your first for loop will only ever loop once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy string this way in `C`. Maximum what you can do with this, is to copy one char from one array to another. But in this case most probably even this won't happen, because index 21 is out of your arrays.

```
newStr[21] = userString[21];
```

replace it with this

```
strcpy(newStr, userString);
```

Also this loop is incorrect, it will give wanted result just in case the first char of `userString` equals to target result

```
      for(j = 0; userString[j] !='\0'; j++)
      {
            if(userString[j] != mytarget[0])
            {
                             printf("Character not found, try again\n\n");
                             notfoundFlag = true;
                             break;
            }
            break;
      }
```

rewrite it with something like that :

```
          for(j = 0; userString[j] !='\0'; j++)
          {
                if(userString[j] == mytarget[0])
                {
                                 printf("Character found\n\n");
                                 found = true;
                                 break;
                }
          }
          if(!found)continue;
```

and remove that `&` before `newStr` in `printf` statement

```
printf("\nWord is : \" %s \" \n\n", newStr);
```